# accessing "sql server 2012" with "native client 10"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-native-client

I am using native client 10.0 to access Sql Server 2012 from Windows XP in a testing environment with success until now. Microsoft advises to upgrade XP machines to Windows 7 or 8 to instal Native Client 12. I would like to hear from anybody using the same solution as mine  or if there is a clar problem to not use natve client 10.0 with Sql Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will run into too many problems using v10 of the native client for just normal queries, but you will lose some of the functionality available in SQL 2012 such as the ability to set ApplicationIntent when using SQL Server 2012 AlwaysOn Availability Groups.

If you're not using these features then you're probably ok, other than having the security issues present in using an OS that's nearly 13 years old and rapidly running out of extended support ;-)